# HAproxy giving PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR in TCP mode

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I'm having a problem with configuring HAproxy in tcp mode to forward SSL connections to my backends.

Here's my haproxy configuration:

```
global
  maxconn 10000
  user haproxy
  group haproxy

defaults
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 30s
  timeout server 30s
  log global
  mode tcp
  maxconn 3000

backend lamacorp_ynh_web
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server lamacorp_ynh 172.20.20.2:443

backend lamacorp_ynh
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server lamacorp_ynh 172.20.20.2

backend duck
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  server duck 127.0.0.1

frontend www
  mode tcp
  option tcplog

  bind 200.200.200.200:80
  bind 200.200.200.200:443

  acl lamacorp_www1 hdr(host) -i domain.com
  acl lamacorp_www2 hdr(host) -i www.domain.com

  acl lamacorp_hub hdr(host) -i hub.domain.com
  acl lamacorp_chat hdr(host) -i chat.domain.com
  acl lamacorp_cloud hdr(host) -i cloud.domain.com
  acl lamacorp_git hdr(host) -i git.domain.com
  acl lamacorp_mail hdr(host) -i mail.domain.com
  acl lamacorp_apps hdr(host) -i apps.domain.com

  acl risson_www1 hdr(host) -i domain2.com
  acl risson_www2 hdr(host) -i www.domain2.com


  use_backend duck if lamacorp_www1
  use_backend duck if lamacorp_www2

  use_backend lamacorp_ynh_web if lamacorp_hub
  use_backend lamacorp_ynh_web if lamacorp_chat
  use_backend lamacorp_ynh_web if lamacorp_cloud
  use_backend lamacorp_ynh_web if lamacorp_git
  use_backend lamacorp_ynh_web if lamacorp_mail
  use_backend lamacorp_ynh_web if lamacorp_apps

  use_backend duck if risson_www1
  use_backend duck if risson_www2

frontend mail
  mode tcp
  option tcplog

  bind 200.200.200.200:25
  bind 200.200.200.200:587
  bind 200.200.200.200:993

  default_backend lamacorp_ynh
```

`curl -vvvkL https://172.20.20.2:443` from behind the HAproxy gives a correct answer (as does `curl`ing the other backend). Both backends use self-signed certificates.

However, `curl -vvvkL https://200.200.200.200:443` gives:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to domain.com (200.200.200.200) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to domain.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to domain.com443
```

and `curl -vvvkL http://hub.lama-corp.space:80` gives:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hub.lama-corp.space (200.200.200.200) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host domain.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

The mail forwarding seems to be working correctly. SSL termination is expected to be done by the backends. Any tip to refactor that config is also welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It's hard to know where to even start, but should first review and eliminate the warnings I suspect you are getting when you start/reload/restart the proxy, and then review the HAProxy logs while making these test requests, which will almost certainly reveal that the correct backend is not being selected, quite likely no backend at all, which would explain these errors in `mode tcp`.